# LWJGL True Type Fonts - Calculate width and height of box

Tags: lwjgl, slick, text

I want to center some text on the screen. At the moment I divide the display height and width by two, and then render. But I also need the height and width of the textbox, so I can subtract it from the box position, making it complete center.

[image]

As you can see the text is not in center.

How can I calculate the width and height of some [text](http://wiki.lwjgl.org/wiki/Slick-Util_Library_-_Part_3_-_TrueType_Fonts_for_LWJGL)?

**Edit:** It's not a solution to multiply the font size by number of chars, as a 'W' is much wider than a '.'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the [Javadocs](http://slick.ninjacave.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/TrueTypeFont.html#getWidth(java.lang.String)) for Slicks TrueTypeFont. It has a Method `public int getWidth(java.lang.String whatchars)` to get the width of a particular String.

To draw perfectly centered it is then simply

```
int positionX = (windowWidth - textWidth) / 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use`Display.getWidth() / 2 - (Your truetypefont).getWidth(your text) / 2` to center it horizontally